# How to make an AND operation on 2 numbers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, bitwise-operators

I want to know how to perform an and operation on 2 numbers in MATLAB

```
ex :-

x = 31   '11111' ;

y = 23   '10111' ;
```

If I use the AND operation on this 2 numbers I will get

```
z = x AND y
```

`z` will be `23` due to AND operation

How can I do this in MATLAB ?

Answer (score 10):

You can just use the `bitand` function, e.g.

```
octave-3.2.3:1> x = 31
x =  31
octave-3.2.3:2> y = 23
y =  23
octave-3.2.3:3> z = bitand(x, y)
z =  23
```